# numpy 1.9.3, ImportError: No module named _globals

Tags: python, numpy, conda

For dependency reasons (using mayavi) I have to use `numpy v1.9.3` in a conda python2.7 virtualenv.

However numpy import fails:

```
(python2) User@P-EliteBook-840-G3:~$ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/User/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    from ._globals import ModuleDeprecationWarning, VisibleDeprecationWarning
ImportError: No module named _globals
```

And indeed there is no `_globals.py` in `/home/User/anaconda3/envs/python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/`
If I install numpy 1.11, then the import works fine. Any idea what's causing this issue ?

I have installed numpy with `conda install numpy=1.9`, inside my python2 environment.

Comment: It isn't in numpy version 1.8 (np.version.version '1.8.0') and there is no indication when it was installed https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/_globals.py

Comment: @NaN I'm sorry, I agree but I'm not sure I get your point?

Comment: I checked the actual script on GitHub.  Usually if it is an important addition, the will indicate which version it was added.  From there you can figure out which other modules call it.  In this case, references to it only appear twice, so a full install of a newer version will definitely fix it, but in this case just copying the script over would suffice for them most part

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problems when using numpy 1.7 in python 2.7. It is simply because lower version of numpy is only compatible with python 2.6. The solution is either upgrade your numpy or downgrade python.

Anyway, the ultimate solution is to use `conda create -n` to build virtual environments for different projects. The developments in various packages are just so vastly different that no one can really track all of them.